# Trying to match nodes between similar graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, pattern-recognition, subgraph, isomorphism

I am looking for an algorithm to match nodes in similar graphs. The number of nodes are not equal, but each graph does represent the same system.

So, I'm looking for similar or fuzzy graph matching or pattern recognition.

Where do I start?

Undirected
Vertex-labelled
Multigraph
Weighted
Sparse
Nodes: 2,172
Edges: 3,000

Nodes have a number of independent attributes. Edges have one attribute, similar to length. Node and edge attributes are not identical for corresponding nodes and edges between the two graphs.

This problem is described in technical papers as partial isomorphism, graph alignment and maximum common subgraph

Comment: Anyone tried using https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/codes/netalign/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic algorithm for partial isomorphism between two graphs A and B ..

---

**Algorithm**

```
Given:
- graph A
- graph B
- threshold on A, p in [0.0,1.0)
- threshold on B, q in [0.0,1.0)

1. define: list T = { Nodes in graph B }

2. define: c = 0

3. for every Node i in graph A
   {
       for every Node j in list T
       {
           if(i and j are equivlant)
           {
               c = c + 1

               remove j from list T
           }
       }
   }

4. calculate: x = number of nodes in graph A / c

5. calculate: y = number of nodes in graph B / c

6. return (x > p AND y > q)
```

---

**Example**

**Rule:** Node i and Node j are equivalent if they have same degree.

**Constant:** Threshold on A, p = 0.95 ~ 95%.

**Constant:** Threshold on B, q = 0.75 ~ 75%.

**Output:** The algorithm will return TRUE for any graph B that has set of nodes that make of 75% or more of it equivalent to set of nodes that make 95% or more of graph A